# How to tell where a variable is coming from?

Tags: cmake, cmake-language

I have a directory with `CMakeLists.txt`. And it invokes a CMake module `module1.cmake` file located elsewhere.

`module1.cmake` will reference a variable named `XXX`, which may come from:

1. the environment variable `%XXX%`.
2. the command line through `cmake -D XXX=`
3. `XXX` defined in the invoking directory's `CMakeLists.txt` through `set()`.
4. and the CACHE entry in the previously configured build folder

Then `module1.cmake` will store the variable `XXX` into the CACHE.

**In the `module1.cmake` file**, I need to tell where `XXX` is from because I need to treat them differently.

For 1, I can check the value of `$ENV{XXX}`.

For 4, I was thinking about using `get_property(cached_XXX CACHE XXX PROPERTY VALUE)` and check the value of `cached_XXX`. But it turns out the `-D XXX=` option **always** update the CACHE entry. So I cannot tell if the `cached_XXX` value is from an old CACHE or from the current `-D` option.

So after all, how can I tell between **2, 3 and 4**?

Comment: For 4, you can use [$CACHE{VAR}](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CACHE.html?highlight=read%20cache) available since CMake 3.13.

Comment: Sorry, you will run into the same problem as with your solution via `get_property`...